# LINQ- to retrieve the third layer list of objects from a list which contains three layers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure like in the following.

```
   CategoryA
   {
         CategoryB
         {
              CategoryC
              {

              }
         }

   }
```

I have a LINQ query to get a list of objects.

```
  var ls = CategoryA.CategoryB.Where(x => x.CategoryBObjectId == someId);
```

This returns a list of CategoryB objects.

And then I want some CategoryC objects.

```
 var ls2= ls.Where(x=>x.Any(y=>y.CategoryCObjectId==someAnotherID))
```

But what ls2 returns is CategoryB objects.

What I want is a list of CategoryC objects fulfilling the condition specified.

Anyone who can help me to change the LINQ query accordingly ?

Comment: You need to clarify, ls2 is already a CategoryC list with a condition specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SelectMany.

```
var data = CategoryA.CategoryB
    .Where(b => b.CategoryBObjectId == someBid)
    .SelectMany(b => b.CategoryC)
    .Where(c => c.CategoryCObjectId == someCid)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you already get categor c when you get category b

so instead search like this i think

```
var ls2= ls.Where(x=>x.Any(y=>y.CategoryC.CategoryCObjectId==someAnotherID))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your second query, there you again filtering values from categoryB.
Your second query need to go like this.

```
var ls2= ls.CategoryC.Where(x => x.CategoryBObjectId == someId);
```

Comment: ls is an IEnumerable, so it won't have a property CategoryC.